# How to avoid dozer mapping fields while using beanfactory?

Tags: field, factory, dozer

So im using a bean factory when converting from a presentation object to another type:

```
  <mapping type="one-way">
    <class-a>com.dynamicform.DynamicFieldTemplateDPO</class-a>
    <class-b bean-factory="com.services.translate.DynamicFieldTemplateDozerFactory">com.modules.dynamicform.domain.DynamicFieldTemplate</class-b>
   <field-exclude>
       <a>form</a>
       <b>form</b>
   </field-exclude>
</mapping>
```

And recently the DPO object got a big upgrade on newly added field properties. But it seems that using the factory doesn't avoid dozer to still try and map all the fields after it finishes running the bean. So the question is, do i need to set the exclude option to all the other fields?Or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by putting a wildcard="false" on the mapping. This way your new generated bean won't have the other fields overridden by the source object values.